# Oracle SQL: Sums from a table with multiple joins and conditions

Tags: sql, syntax, oracle10g

I am trying to get a result from a single query to display the sum of a quantity even when a row is not found.

This query does exactly what I want:

```
select max(m.item_number), max(m.item_description), 
       max(m.uom), sum(nvl(i.qty_ordered,0))
from (((dex.ITEM_MASTER m FULL JOIN dex.order_request_items i ON m.item_number = i.item_number)  
                          FULL JOIN dex.order_request h ON h.orderid = i.orderid)
                          FULL JOIN dex.customer c ON h.customer_number = c.customer_number)
where m.item_number in ('199', '198', '11415', '11425', '11435', '1145', '766')
group by m.item_number
order by 1
```

and returns this

```
MAX(M.ITEM_NUMBER) MAX(M.ITEM_DESCRIPTION)     MAX(M.UOM) "SUM(NVL(I.QTY_ORDERED,0))"
11415              Bananas HALF CASE GREEN     1/2        0
11425              Bananas HALF CASE GREEN TIP 1/2        0
11435              Bananas HALF CASE RIPE      1/2        0
1145               Bananas HALF CASE           1/2        5
198                Watermelons SEEDLESS        EACH       0
199                Watermelons                 EACH       80
766                Pumpkins EACH               EACH       0
```

This displays the zeroes for rows that have no quantities just fine. The problem occurs when I add additional conditions that are needed to narrow down the data.
I need the same kind of result with the additional conditions in this query

```
select max(m.item_number), max(m.item_description), 
       max(m.uom), sum(nvl(i.qty_ordered,0))
from (((dex.ITEM_MASTER m FULL JOIN dex.order_request_items i ON m.item_number = i.item_number)  
                          FULL JOIN dex.order_request h ON h.orderid = i.orderid)
                          FULL JOIN dex.customer c ON h.customer_number = c.customer_number)                      
where m.item_number in ('199', '198', '11415', '11425', '11435', '1145', '766')
and     h.REQUEST_DELIVERY_DATE = TO_DATE('10/24/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
and     c.subcontractorid is null
and     h.request_state <> 'Incomplete'
group by m.item_number
order by 1
```

That query though returns this result.

```
MAX(M.ITEM_NUMBER) MAX(M.ITEM_DESCRIPTION)     MAX(M.UOM) "SUM(NVL(I.QTY_ORDERED,0))"
199                Watermelons                 EACH       31
```

The rows that should show a zero are now gone. Is it possible to have all the rows like the first result show when using additional conditions?

Thanks!

Comment: We would need to see the data before answering this; my guess would be you are filtering out the records where quantity is zero as you have added additional conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select max(m.item_number), max(m.item_description), 
       max(m.uom), sum(nvl(i.qty_ordered,0))
from (((dex.ITEM_MASTER m FULL JOIN dex.order_request_items i ON m.item_number = i.item_number)  
                          FULL JOIN dex.order_request h ON h.orderid = i.orderid)
                          FULL JOIN dex.customer c ON h.customer_number = c.customer_number)                      
where m.item_number in ('199', '198', '11415', '11425', '11435', '1145', '766')
and     h.REQUEST_DELIVERY_DATE = TO_DATE('10/24/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
and     c.subcontractorid is null
and     nvl(h.request_state,'Complete') <> 'Incomplete'
group by m.item_number
order by 1
```

When you add new condition on h.request_state you must consider possible NULL data, adding NVL can help.

hth